# Managing bash script for different linux distros

Tags: bash, stdout, monitor, mode

I'm developing a wifi-tool script in bash. I'm a newbie and it's giving me a headache. There are one point of my script in which I need to "cut" the stdout in order to get the correct value. I already have it developed and working... but the behavior of the stdout of the commands is different depending on the Linux distro.

For example. I want to check the new name of an interface after setting it in monitor mode. The stdout of the command (airmon-ng start wlan3) in Kali linux is this:

```
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy2    wlan3       rt2800usb   Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070

    (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy2]wlan3 on [phy2]wlan3mon)
    (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy2]wlan3)
```

I got from this the desired name "wlan3mon" with this in my script:

```
new_interface=$(airmon-ng start $interface | grep monitor | cut -d ']' -f 3)
new_interface=${new_interface:: -1}
```

The output in Backtrack Linux for the same command (airmon-ng start wlan3) is this:

```
Interface       Chipset         Driver

wlan3           Ralink RT2870/3070      rt2800usb - [phy3]
                            (monitor mode enabled on mon3)
```

I take the desired name "mon3" from this output doing this in my script:

```
new_interface=$(airmon-ng start $interface|grep monitor|awk '{print $5}')
new_interface=${new_interface:: -1}
```

As you see the stdout of the commands are quite different. Not sure if there is an "universal" way to do this... of if I must insert some control before in order to detect which distro is running or if there is a better way to detect this better than managing the stdout of the command. Any suggestion we'll be welcome.

Thanks to all! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The different output may be due to different versions of the `airmon-ng` executable, or possibly just different invocations of it depending on the Linux distro.

It's a guess, but I would think `airmon-ng start` is really the output of the script that launches the service.  It might be a script in `/etc/init.d` or perhaps a script called when networking services are initialized.  Typically these scripts are just shell scripts that make underlying calls to the real executable software.

So if you can find that ... and it may *be* `airmon-ng` chances are it has some other options that may display output more consistently.  Try `airmon-ng -h` or `man airmon-ng` to see if there is help or a manual page.  It might also be version differences -- try `airmon-ng -v` (or maybe `-V` or `--version`).  Actually, just looked on google and found this page http://linux.die.net/man/1/airmon-ng which says it is a script, and points to some config options in `/etc/kismet/kismet.conf`

Start by looking at the script (use `which airmon-ng` to find its path) then examine the script itself to see what it does.  There may be clues to how to get at the information you're looking for a different way.

Comment: Yeah. I noticed in both distros airmon is in /usr/sbin . As you said is a bash script. There is no -v or --version parameter and looking inside there are quite different too. I think I'll do some checks at the beginning of my script to check using uname -a or something like that if there is a Kali or Backtrack and maybe I'll restrict the use only to both doing different commands when needed. :/

Comment: So sounds like it's a different script using the same name.  Ultimately, it's likely just a wrapper that calls some lower-level networking command, so maybe that's where you need to look.  If that's not obvious, edit your question and post the script contents (or links to it if it's big).

Answer (score 0):

Regexes to the rescue!

Try

```
new_interface=$(airmon-ng start $interface | sed -n 's/.*monitor.*enabled.*\W\(\w*\))/\1/p')
```

This piped the output to sed which runs a regex which searches for alphanumeric characters before a close bracket at the of the line. It then prints these characters and only those because of the -n flag. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [outthentic](https://github.com/melezhik/outthentic) - multipurpose script framework, it's possible write a cross platforms bash scripts there. Here is example snippet:

```
shopt -s nocasematch;

if [[ $os =~ "debian" ]]; then
  # some code here
elif [[ "$os" =~ "ubuntu" ]]; then
  # some code here
elif [[ "$os" =~ "centos" ]]; then
  # some code here
else
  echo "unknown os: $os"
  exit 1
fi
```

Once your script is done you may distribute it across your servers with the help of [sparrow](https://github.com/melezhik/sparrow) which is quite handy.

If you need Kali and Blacktrack linux gets added to recognized os list - let me know.

PS disclosure - I am outthentic/sparrow author.